# Django - In app urls not working properly

Tags: python, django

I am trying to include the url of my app to my project's url as stated below but there seems to be a problem, please help me figure out what is the problem. 
My project name is trydjango and this is `urls.py` file in it

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('teacher/', include('teacher.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', homeView, name='home'),
]
```

and this is `teacher.urls` file

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import addTeacherView, listTeacherView, teacherIndexView, deleteTeacherView, editTeacherView

app_name = "teacher"
urlpatterns = [
    path('addTeacher/', addTeacherView, name='add-teacher'),
    path('listTeacher/', listTeacherView, name='list-teacher'),
    path('teacherIndex/<int:my_id>/', teacherIndexView, name='teacher-index'),
    path('deleteTeacher/<int:my_id>/',
         deleteTeacherView, name='delete-teacher-view'),
    path('editTeacher/<int:my_id>/', editTeacherView, name='edit-teacher'),
]
```

and in models.py I included the app name at reverse method

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=72)
    email = models.EmailField()
    salary = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100000, decimal_places=2)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('teacher:edit-teacher', kwargs={'my_id': self.id})
```

Please help me find the problem
Thanks in advance!

edit: the error is here, my reputation is below 10 it doesn't allow me to add images here! but here is a copy of the errors it shows

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'add-teacher' not found. 'add-teacher' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 2.1.7
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'add-teacher' not found. 'add-teacher' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Exception Location: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 622
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.2
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\123\\src',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 22 Mar 2019 20:29:59 +0000
Error during template rendering
In template C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\123\src\teacher\templates\teacher\base.html, error at line 19

Reverse for 'add-teacher' not found. 'add-teacher' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
9       <title>Document</title>
10      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
11      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
12  
13  </head>
14  
15  <body>
16      <nav>
17          <a class="logo" href="{% url 'home' %}">LOGO</a>
18          <div class="navbar">
19              <a href="{% url 'add-teacher' %}">Add Teacher</a>
20              <a href="{% url 'list-teacher' %}">List Teacher</a>
21          </div>
```

Comment: What are you doing and what are you seeing happen?

Comment: when I run server, it shows Error during template rendering

Comment: what error?????

Comment: I'm going to guess you're using class based views. If that's the case you need to use `editTeacherView.as_view()` in your urls.py

Comment: I just edited my answer to you the errors therein

Comment: @schillingt no I am not using class based views.

Comment: ProTip:  A code block of the actual ouput is preferred over a picture of your error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're missing the namespace for a few of your url calls. In your template you have `{% url 'add-teacher' %}`. That should be `{% url 'teacher:add-teacher' %}`. Look for any other cases of your teacher urls as well.

Answer (score 1):

I your templates you use addresses like this one:

```
<a href="{% url 'add-teacher' %}">Add Teacher</a>
```

you must change this types of addressing to this one (because of app `teacher`):

```
<a href="{% url 'teacher:add-teacher' %}">Add Teacher</a>
```